# how to remove duplicates including strings in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, unique

I want to remove duplicates from numpy array.

```
>data = np.array([[1,"a",3,3,4],
                  [1,8,9,9,4],
                  [1,"a",3,3,4]])

>new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
>uniques = np.unique(new_array)
>uniques

output: array(['1', '3', '4', '8', '9', 'a'], dtype='<U1')
```

But what I want is

```
output: np.array([[1,"a",3,3,4],[1,8,9,9,4]])
```

How can I do this?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy is bad at handling arrays with mixed datatypes, so how about using pandas `drop_duplicates` instead?

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,"a",3,3,4],[1,8,9,9,4], [1,"a",3,3,4]]
pd.DataFrame(data).drop_duplicates().values

# array([[1, 'a', 3, 3, 4],
#        [1, 8, 9, 9, 4]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks and i tried but it still returns `array([['1', 'a', '3', '3', '4'],
       ['1', '8', '9', '9', '4']], dtype=object)`

Comment: @user9191983 Please use `data = np.array([[1,"a",3,3,4],
                  [1,8,9,9,4],
                  [1,"a",3,3,4]], dtype=object)` to initialise your data, or else it won't work.

Comment: it worked! thanks and you gave me some more tips than you really meant!

Comment: @user9191983 You're welcome! You can [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) as well if you found it helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `vstack`:

```
print(np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in data}))
```

Output:

```
[['1' 'a' '3' '3' '4']
 ['1' '8' '9' '9' '4']]
```

You can't make them integers because numpy doesn't support mixed-typed data.